# Dot '.' in interface name Map.Entry in Java

Tags: java

As I know one cannot have '.' in class or interface name in java. However, it looks like Map.Entry interface doesn't follow that rule. Please correct my understanding or the reason behind that '.'.

Comment: It is way to refer to inner class/interface.

Comment: `Entry` is an inner interface of `Map`.

Comment: You don't have to refer to it like that: you could import `java.util.Map.Entry`, and just use the simple name `Entry`. Or you could refer to it with the fully-qualified `java.util.Map.Entry`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read this:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html?is-external=true

Entry is nested inside Map, you use dot ('.') to access it.

Read this as well: https://dzone.com/articles/what-inner-interface-java

Quote from `dzone` (second link):

> Inner interface is also called nested interface, which means declare
>   an interface inside of another interface. For example, the Entry
>   interface is declared in the Map interface.

```
public interface Map {
    interface Entry{
        int getKey();
    }

    void clear();
}
```

> **Why Use Inner Interface?**
>
> There are several compelling reasons for using inner interface:
>
> - It is a way of logically grouping interfaces that are only used in    one place.
> - It increases encapsulation.
> - Nested interfaces can lead to more    readable and maintainable code.
>
> One example of inner interface used in
>   java standard library is java.util.Map and Java.util.Map.Entry. Here
>   java.util.Map is used also as a namespace. Entry does not belong to
>   the global scope, which means there are many other entities that are
>   Entries and are not necessary Map’s entries. This indicates that Entry
>   represents entries related to the Map.